# How to convert a string containing a timestamp to a simple Date in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, csv

I have exported an Access table into a .csv file and am importing that .csv file into a MySql table.

After importing everything, I currently have a column in MySQL called **Time** that contains string data (VARCHAR):

```
7/29/2008 10:28:38
```

Importing this timestamp data from Access using a .csv file would work correctly only if I imported it into a VARCHAR field in MySql.

Anyway, I'd like to convert the **Time** VARCHAR field containing:

```
7/29/2008 10:28:38
```

To a simple MySql Date field (called **Time2** containing just the date:

```
7/29/2008
```

I've tried doing so with the following query:

```
UPDATE members SET Time2 = STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I'm not sure how I can process the original Time field to be able to correctly extract the DATE info from it and then store it in the Time2 field.  Do I first need to covert the original Time field into a timestamp, then convert it and store it as a simple date using DATE_FORMAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is `%c/%e/%Y`:

```
UPDATE members SET Time2 = STR_TO_DATE(Time, '%c/%e/%Y')
```

where

- %c is the month, numeric, without leading zeros
- %e is the day of the month, numeric, probably without leading zeros
- %Y is the year

Here you can find a reference of the [format string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Thanks, I eventually figured out how to import the date strings directly from the CSV file using a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement that simultaneously formatted the dates into the correct MySQL date field, using your help on syntax and your reference of the format string link.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get `STR_TO_DATE` to work when doing a `SELECT`, changed `STR_TO_DATE` to `DATE_FORMAT` and I have `mm/dd/yyyy` -

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Time, '%c/%e/%Y') FROM the_table_name
```

> e.g. DATE_FORMAT('2013-08-14 09:42:05')
>
> gives 8/14/2013

Answer (score -1):

```
DATEADD(second, yourTime, CONVERT(DATETIME, '1970-01-01', 102)))
```